# Mean average error normalized by the standard deviation of the target

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, standard-deviation, mae

I'm working on a regression model, aiming at prediction age from structured data.
I'm using the mean average error (MAE) as evaluation metric, and want to compare my performances with state-of-the-art performances. The thing is that we are not using the same dataset, so the target variable (age) doesn't have the same range.
Having an MAE of 2 if age is ranging from 2 to 5 isn't the same as if the age is ranging from 2 to 40.

Does it makes sense to compare MAE/std(age) instead of MAE alone?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Here is a reference that may help 'MAE and RMSE — Which Metric is Better?' at https://medium.com/human-in-a-machine-world/mae-and-rmse-which-metric-is-better-e60ac3bde13d , and also one may want to distinguished between the relative error and the absolute error, discussed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error .

Comment: Thanks for the resources. However, I don't see clearly how this is solving my problem. My goal is to minimize the impact of the dataset to be able to discuss SOTA performances. If I look at the article on "approximation error", it should be better to divide the MAE by the magnitude of the age?